# how to set the state to the props values and have the value appear in a form on first render in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

how to set the default values of state variables to the prop values.

I have tried setting them in the construction as such:

```
this.state = {
   a: this.props.a,
   b: this.props.b
 }
```

but when I use a controlled input in forms.
the values set the previous values on first render and not the set values.

Using lifecycle methods like componentWillMount and componentDidMount produces the same result.

I am thinking of using refs but is there a another way.

Comment: Please, add a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following workaround

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if (nextProps.inputValue !== this.props.inputValue) {
    this.setState({ inputVal: nextProps.inputValue })
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one for static state define

```
this.state = {
     header: "Header from state...",
     content: "Content from state..."
  }
```